# +sign as text in variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code:

```js
var text = "test+subject co+vid banana";
var words = (text.match(/\w+/mg));
var random = [];
var rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
random.push( words[rn]);
console.log(words.splice(rn, 1));
```

The variable `random` gets set to "test" or "co" instead of "test+subject" or "co+vid". What have I done wrong?

EDIT: Sorry, I was unclear; I also want it to catch single words without a plus (like the banana I added to the list)

Comment: [`+` is a metacharacter](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) in regular expressions. The `\w` character class does not contain `+` characters.

Comment: Use `[\w+]+` as the regex

Comment: Or even `\S+` ..

Comment: @Mandy8055 Sorry, I didn't explain myself correctly, I have edited the topic.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` is a special regex-character. If you want to match it literally you have to escape it using `\+`

Comment: OP does not want to match `\w\+` though

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself correctly, I have edited the topic.

Comment: Also if I do:
var text = "test\+subject co\+vid banana";
it sets to "test" or "co"

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Nevertheless here is how you match those + concatenated worde: [\w]+\+\w+

Comment: Matching the single words is just \w+